# Why is there a Visa for the Ark?

Tags: snuggle-truck

In Snuggle Truck, there is an odd behaviour when I first start the game. When looking at the Ark medal for the first time after starting the game up, there is a picture of someone's Visa:

[image: pic of strangeness]

As soon as anything is clicked, the main image goes back to an ark again, but the thumbnail view remains a visa until you change the selected track.

[image: Normal behaviour]

I realize that this might be just an easter egg, but I hadn't noticed the behaviour until recently. If it is an easter egg, I don't get the joke.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know the meaning of the Visa picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a bug related to the fact that the game wasn't always called Snuggle Truck - it began life as a game called [**Smuggle** Truck](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/04/28/smuggle-truck-now-snuggle-truck-on-ios-after-apple-rejection-pc/) - a game about smuggling illegal immigrants across the border.

They changed the content of the game after it was rejected from the app store, but supposedly (if the video in the linked article is correct) all the "smuggle" content was left in the PC/Mac version of the game, and can be toggled.

It's highly likely that what you're seeing is the "smuggle" variant of the medal.

Comment: I realized that Snuggle Truck was a re-skinning of Smuggle Truck, but  I didn't know they left the old skins in the game. I'm playing with the Steam version, and it does't appear to have a "smuggle mode", oh well. :/ Thanks for explaining that.